# Hull White Equation Derivation

Tags: hullwhite, differential-equations

Hello I need your help. 
I found the formula for deriving $A(t,T)$ and $B(t,T)$ in Hull White paper is like this

$BB_{tT} - B_{t}B_{T} - B_{T} = 0$ and
$ABA_{tT} - BA_{t}A_{T} - AA_{t}B_{T} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t)A^2B^2B_{T} = 0$

and they are resulting in this
$B(t,T) = \frac{B(0,T) - B(0,t)}{\frac{\partial B(0,t)}{\partial t}}$ and
$\hat{A}(t,T) = \hat{A}(0,T) - \hat{A}(0,t) - B(t,T)\frac{\partial \hat{A}(0,t)}{\partial t} -  \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[B(t,T)\frac{\partial B(0,t)}{\partial t}\Bigg]^{2}\int_{0}^{t} \Bigg[\frac{\sigma(\tau)}{\frac{\partial{B(0,\tau)}}{\partial \tau}}\Bigg]^{2}d\tau$

where $\hat{A}(t,T) = \ln{|A(t,T)|}$. 
Anyone know how to derive the solution? Please this is for my thesis

Comment: See [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31995/zero-coupon-bond-pricing-formula-using-hull-white/31998#31998) and [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31848/hull-white-formula-on-wikipedia-correct/31852#31852) for an alternative derivation.