# Hull-White model: match between HJM framework and short model formulation

Tags: hullwhite, short-rate, heath-jarrow-morton

I need to show that the Hull-White model $$dr=(\theta(t)-ar)dt+\sigma dW^Q$$ corresponds to the Heath-Jarrow-Morton formulation $$df(t,T)=\alpha(t,T)dt+\sigma e^{-a(T-t)}dW^Q.$$
I obtained the drift by with drift condition $$\alpha(t,T)=\sigma(t,T)\int_t^T\sigma(t,s)ds,$$ where $\sigma(t,T)=\sigma e^{-a(T-t)}.$ Then, I integrated the resulting $df(t,T)$ and set $T=t\rightarrow f(t,t)=r(t)$. Finally, I looked for the differential $dr(t)$, but the resulting expression looks completely diffeent form the Hull-White formulation.

Could you show me how to perform needed calculations?

Thank you, 
Giulio

Comment: what is your $f(0, T)$?

Comment: I set the initial condition as $f^\star(0,T)$, i.e. market forward rate. I am following Björk (2009) p.393.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
\begin{align*}
f(t, T) = f(0, T) + \int_0^t\alpha(u,T)du+\int_0^t\sigma e^{-a(T-u)}dW_u,
\end{align*}
where, based on [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31848/hull-white-formula-on-wikipedia-correct/31852#31852), 
\begin{align*}
f(0, T) = \int_0^T \theta(u) e^{-a(T-u)} du - \frac{\sigma^2}{2a^2}\big(e^{-a T} -1\big)^2 + e^{-a T} r_0.
\end{align*}
Note also that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t\alpha(u,T)du &= \int_0^t\sigma(u,T)\int_u^T\sigma(u,s)dsdu\\
&=\int_0^t\sigma e^{-a(T-u)}\int_u^T\sigma e^{-a(s-u)}dsdu\\
&=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2a^2}\Big[\big(e^{-a(T-t)}-1\big)^2 - \big(e^{-aT}-1 \big)^2 \Big].
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
r_t &= f(t, t)\\
&=e^{-at}\int_0^t \theta(u) e^{au} du + e^{-a t} r_0+e^{-at}\int_0^t\sigma e^{au}dW_u.
\end{align*}
Then, it is clear that
\begin{align*}
dr_t &= -ar_t dt + \theta(t) dt + \sigma dW_t\\
&= (\theta(t) - a r) dt + \sigma dW_t.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much, Gordon! :)

Comment: You are welcome.