# Can volatility assume negative values under multi-factor HJM framework?

Tags: interest-rates, calibration, heath-jarrow-morton

I could find any reference restricting the sign of the volatilities in the multi-factor HJM framework.

Can someone please confirm if $\sigma_i(t,T)$ can assume negative values for some $i,t$ and $T$?

$$
df(t,T) = \left(\sum_i \sigma_i(t,T)\int_t^T \sigma_i(t,u) du \right) dt + \sum_i \sigma_i(t,T) dW_i(t)
$$

Answer (score 1):

At first, I also could not find a single source that formally restricts $\sigma_i(t,T)$. However, the formally very precise article [1] explicitly states that the $\sigma_i(t,T)$ are assumed to be non-negative:

> [...] the volatilities $\sigma_i(\cdot,\cdot,\omega_t)$ belong to $\mathcal{F}$, the set of all functions
> defined from ${(t, T ) : t \in [0, T ]}\times\Omega$ onto $\mathbb{R}$, that are $\mathbb{P}$-almost
> everywhere non-negative, bounded, square integrable on any finite time
> horizon, and Lipschitz continuous with respect to the second variable.
> Further the $\sigma_i(\cdot,\cdot,\omega_t)$ are jointly measurable from $\mathcal{B} {(t, T ) : t \in [0, T]} \times \mathcal{F}_T → \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra restricted to $[0, T]$.

Most references quietly assume this by stating that the $\sigma_i(t,T)$ are volatility functions.

Additionally, the volatility functions are usually modeled as a non-negative process, for example when showing its correspondence to a Hull-White model [2].

[1] [Tchuindjo, L. (2009). An extended Heath–Jarrow–Morton risk-neutral drift. *Applied Mathematics Letters, 22(3)*, 396–400.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965908001663)

[2] [Hull-White model: match between HJM framework and short model formulation](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/53725/hull-white-model-match-between-hjm-framework-and-short-model-formulation)